# How to write assertion that checks Controller method renders specific view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4

I am running Rails 4 with Ruby 2.1.1.

I have in my Controller 

  `def home
    render :index
  end`

and I am writing a Unit::Test to check that the controller renders the view `index` with the method `home`.

How would I write the assertion? So far I have

`test "home should have index" do
  assert true
end`

My test passes, of course, because I have `assert true`, but upon looking over the documentation, and having tinkered around, I am still unsure how to write a proper functional test for a Controller. Many sources are incomplete or vague, and seeing how no simple Stack Overflow question regarding writing a simple functional test using Unit::Test appears on Stack Overflow, I figured this would be a great question.

All I want is a clear answer to assert that my functional test checks that the `home` method renders `index`. Once I figure out how a basic functional test is written, I think I'll be able to proceed to testing the rest of my app.

Cheers

TL;DR I don't know how to write a basic functional test. How do I do that? Please be Unit::Test beginner friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [assert_template](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TemplateAssertions.html#method-i-assert_template) to assert that the request was rendered with the appropriate template file or partials.

```
test "home should have index" do
  get :home
  assert_template 'index'
end
```

Comment: @Altun, That is considered a functional test only for the controller StaticPagesController.  The test should be in the file:  `test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb`.  See the RailsGuide here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-templates-and-layouts

Comment: @infused, thank you very much for the clear and concise answer. Aha!
`assert_template` after `get :home`. As clear and concise as can be. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to `infused`'s answer:

1. That is considered a functional test for a specific controller  *only*, whose features and limitations are described in the RailsGuide [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#functional-tests-for-your-controllers).
2. If your controller's name is StaticPagesController, the test should be in the file:

   `test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb`
3. The RailsGuide describes how to test for a rendered view [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-templates-and-layouts).
4. You can run the tests like this:

   `$ bundle exec rake test`

   or:

   `$ bundle exec rake test:functionals`

> seeing how no simple Stack Overflow question regarding writing a
>   simple functional test using Unit::Test appears on Stack Overflow

That's because Rails has its own testing framework.  The file `test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb` actually looks like this:

```
require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  test 'home should get index' do
    get :home
    assert_template :index
  end

end
```

Note the superclass: `ActionController::TestCase`.  As the RailsGuide [notes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#a-brief-note-about-minitest), `ActionController::TestCase` includes MiniTest, which is [mostly a drop in replacement](http://ruby-doc.org//stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/minitest/unit/rdoc/MiniTest.html) for `Test::Unit`.

Comment: 7stud, your answer was fantastic. It contained more than I needed, but your extra, relevant information will certainly help me become a Test::Unit code monkey. I will recommend this post to anyone I hear asking about functional testing. Many regards.